# How to install Three.js

Tags: three.js

Hello everyone I am new to JavaScript and my job requires me to design in 3d using JavaScript. I went through the website but it says to include three.js. How can I include three.js in the HTML? Is there a standard src that I can include to make my programs execute or is there another way for it ? Any help or recommendations would be gladly accepted.

Comment: I feel your pain!  I have just visited https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation, and it is a nightmare.  It starts by recommending npm, which I am reluctant to do as I want to just include three.js in my sources.  Followed by vague information about "bundling tool" . . . ?  Then, on to CDN or static hosting . . . more waffling about import maps & shims !!!!  Then, another bombshell, "Using three.js in Node.js can be difficult, for two reasons:".  Nice.  Fortunately I have an ancient version of three.js embedded in my project so I don't have to do any of this.

Comment: See my "alternative" documentation below.

Answer (score 9):

if I could offer a friendly suggestion. Three.js is fairly advanced for a first time Javascript programmer, you might want to try some basic tutorials on HTML5 with Javascript, move your way up to library includes and such, then try your hand at Three.js. Here's a couple basic tutorial's on ThreeJS

- http://aerotwist.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/
- http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/#hello-world

However, I digress, to include a library in Javascript you use:

```
<script src="relative_path/library_name.js"></script>
```

In your case, download the zip source, copy the build/three.min.js file to a folder relative to your html (like a "js" folder) and use:

```
<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
```

Kind regards ~D

Answer (score 0):

Or you can include the link directly from GitHub Project:

```
<script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the download link at: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/archive/master.zip

Unzip, and copy any files you want from the build subdirectory to js/ or similar in your project.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install three --save-dev
```

See https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation

Answer (score 0):

To install all the developer dependencies, try this command:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/three
```